# delete a file on my local branch using git

Tags: git, branch

I have some changes in some of my files which were already there. Then I have added a new file in it using

```
git add newfilename
```

I didn't commited yet, Now I want to delete this new file. I can't do the reset as it will reset all other file changes also which I don;t want.

I tried `git checkout newfilename` and usual guesses `delete` and `rm` also but not helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git reset newfilename` will remove it from the index and then you can delete it as usual.

Answer (score 2):

Try a

```
git rm --cached newfilename
```

To at least remove it from the index.

Answer (score 0):

Just you can remove a file from your branch by using this command:

`$git rm file_name`